# Count all the possible values of product of integers from $3$ sets

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

I have the following question:

> Roberta chooses an integer $r$ from the set $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$, an integer $s$
> from the set $\{22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99\}$, and an integer t from the set
> $\{202, 303, 404, 505, 606, 707, 808, 909\}$. How many possible values are there for the product $rst$?

> (A) 85 (B) 81 (C) 90 (D) 84 (E) 80

This is a question from 2019 [Cayley](https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2019/2019CayleyContest.pdf) (Question 24) contest.

I do checked the [answer](https://www.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/contests/past_contests/2019/2019CayleySolution.pdf) (Question 24) for several time, but the answer only use the different possibilities of factor of 5 and factor 7 to count all the possible value which is kind of weird.

Could anyone explain me how to solve this question?

Thanks for any responds!

**Updated:** I see people mentioned in the comment that this question is ridiculous and the answer is useless, doesn't make any sense. I agree. **But since this is a contest question, what would be an alternative and better answer is we don't look at the solution it gives?**

Comment: Just a comment: This is a ridiculous question for a 15 year old. Especially seeing their expected solution process

Comment: This seems like it should be 8x8x8, which should be 512 different values, I don't see how it is any of the listed answers, and their explanation is completely nonsensical and has no real relation to the question. They appear to just be plain wrong, the answer flat out isn't 85.

Comment: @Zoey, I think the answer won't be 512 since there will be some duplicate. For example, 2*404*44 = 2*202*88, but I agree with you that the answer is useless.

Comment: True, didn't take into account same product answers, so it would definitely be below 512, but I *highly* doubt it would be as low as 85.

Comment: It is 85. The following Mathematica code confirms it: Products = 
 DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Table[r*s*t, {r, X}, {s, Y}, {t, Z}]]] (where X,Y,Z are the given sets), and Length[Products] outputs 85.

Comment: @AlfredYerger, Thanks for the answer. But could you explain a little bit about the formula and how you get this? Because the formula is a confused for me.

Comment: I don't know any way of counting it other than to count cases as the answer below suggests. I was just responding to the comment that it must be close to 512.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a somewhat more concise way to enumerate the cases.  The products $rst$ are all of the form $$2^{n_2}3^{n_3}5^{n_5}7^{n_7}11^1 101^1,$$
where $n_2\in\{0,\dots,9\}$, $n_3\in\{0,\dots,6\}$, $n_5\in\{0,\dots,3\}$, and $n_7\in\{0,\dots,3\}$.  If there were no other restrictions, there would be
$$(9+1)(6+1)(3+1)(3+1)=1120$$
possibilities, but we do have restrictions like $n_2+n_3+n_5+n_7 \ge 3$ and $n_5+n_7 \le 3$.

Our approach will be to condition first on $n_5+n_7$ and then on $n_3$.  Note that for a given value of $n_5+n_7$, there are $n_5+n_7+1$ choices of the ordered pair $(n_5,n_7)$.

\begin{matrix}
\hline
n_5+n_7 & n_3 & n_2 & \text{count} \\
\hline
3 & 0 & 0 & (3+1)(1) = 4 \\
\hline
2 & 2 & 0 & (2+1)(1) = 3 \\
2 & 1 & 0,1 & (2+1)(2) = 6 \\
2 & 0 & 1,2,3 & (2+1)(3) = 9 \\
\hline
1 & 4 & 0  & (1+1)(1) = 2 \\
1 & 3 & 0,1  & (1+1)(2) = 4 \\
1 & 2 & 0,\dots,3  & (1+1)(4) = 8 \\
1 & 1 & 1,\dots,4  & (1+1)(4) = 8 \\
1 & 0 & 2,\dots,6  & (1+1)(5) = 10 \\
\hline
0 & 6 & 0  & (0+1)(1) = 1 \\
0 & 5 & 0,1  & (0+1)(2) = 2 \\
0 & 4 & 0,\dots,3  & (0+1)(4) = 4 \\
0 & 3 & 0,\dots,4  & (0+1)(5) = 5 \\
0 & 2 & 1,\dots,6  & (0+1)(6) = 6 \\
0 & 1 & 2,\dots,7  & (0+1)(6) = 6 \\
0 & 0 & 3,\dots,9  & (0+1)(7) = 7 \\
\hline
\text{total} &&& 85 \\
\hline
\end{matrix}

---

It turns out that these are exactly the nonnegative integer solutions to
\begin{align}
n_2 + n_3 + n_5 + n_7 &\ge 3 \\
2n_2 + 3n_3 + 6n_5 + 6n_7 &\le 18 \\
\end{align}
But I don't see any quicker way to count them.

Comment: Really apreciate for the detailed answer. Just wonder what does n2,n3,n4 stand for? Also, we could only choose three number which means the maximum possibility should be 8*8*8 =512. How could it be 1120?

Comment: The variable $n_p$ is the exponent of $p$ in the prime factorization of $rst/(11\times101)$.  The value $1120$ is an overcount that arises from relaxing the restrictions.  The value $85$ is the correct count that respects the restrictions.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at the full solution but I felt it actually reasonable to divide into cases by the number of $5$ and $7$ that appears in $rmn$.

My thought process:

We can ignore $11$ and $101$ and focus on $\{2, 2^2, 2^3, 3, 3^2, 2\times 3, 5, 7\}$. There are a number of ways to count possible values.

We can divide into cases by the number of $2$ that appears in $rmn$. However, there are $10$ cases (0 to 9), and this is not good.

$3$ seems to be a bit better but still have 7 cases (0 to 6) so this is not good either.

$5$ and $7$ are simple. Each has only $4$ cases and there are only $10$ cases combined.

However, you have to divide cases by the number of $2$ and $3$ later anyway. So, this actually does not have a strong advantage.

I would say it is your preference with which number you want to start.